# Is this possible to scroll text in textfield in jQuery or jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am implementing a custom text field in which I can text scroll. It doesn't mean I need scrolling text field. That is default property of text field. I need it to function so that if a user writes text in a text field, he will be able to scroll text horizontally right and left.

```
<div id="p_scents">
    <input type="text" wrap='off' id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
</div>

input {
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -web-kit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
}
```

Comment: If you're making a custom text field, we need to see your code before we can say how to change it.

Comment: here is my fiddle..http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/tZPg4/5936/

Comment: Well that's not a custom text field but ok.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a textarea and set width and height the same as a input (textfield).
With css you can always enable the scrollbar

```
    <textarea style="overflow:auto; width:120px; height:24px; resize: none;" rows=1 wrap="off" ></textarea>
```

Comment: if i am using like 
 <textarea style="overflow:scroll; width:120px; height:70px;"></textarea> it is not scrolling horizontally it scrolling  vertically

Comment: I don't need like that..:(

Comment: with textarea, you cannot scroll horizontally. It automatically wraps word to next lien.

Comment: @Mohit pandey I need text field text scroll horizontally

Comment: <textarea style="overflow:auto; width:120px; height:24px; resize: none;" rows=1 wrap="off" ></textarea>

http://jsfiddle.net/zSrGs/